# Google API Generating a refresh token

Tags: python, api, google-ads-api

I have created a test account in https://console.cloud.google.com/

I followed the instructions in the following link:
[OAuth Web Application Flow](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs/python/oauth-web)

All went ok till Step 3 - Generating a refresh token.
In Step 3:
sub steps 1-4 went ok as describe in the link.

But on sub step 5 I am getting :

> The authentication flow has completed. You may close this window.

and in my cmd I see:

> Access token: XXXXXXXXXX
> Refresh token: None

Can someone please help me to understand what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Nir

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you generate refresh token by using playground?

https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Please follow the link above and screenshot

[image]

Use the same credentials you created using console for test account and generate refresh token.
Please note that if you have not chosen the scope in OAuth consent screen, it won't work.
You need to make sure you are using same scope in playground.
Also, Please make sure that the Google ads is enabled to library of your console page.